# How to migrate create view with flask-migrate?

Tags: postgresql, view, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I create a view model but i can't migrate to create view in database. When i query, database raise a error  `relation "prediction_view" does not exist`

```
class PredictionView(Base):
    __table__ = create_materialized_view(
        name='prediction_view',
        selectable=sa.select(
            ['*'],
            from_obj=(
                Prediction.__table__.join(Claimable, Claimable.prediction_id == Prediction.id)
                .join(UserChoice, UserChoice.prediction_id == Prediction.id)
                .join(Category, Category.id == Prediction.category_id)
                .join(Answer, Answer.prediction_id == Prediction.id)
            )
        ),
        metadata=Base.metadata
    )
```

Comment: The `create_materialized_view()` function that you are using is not part of SQLAlchemy. Where did that come from? My guess is that Alembic does not recognize it.

Comment: I use `from sqlalchemy_utils.view import create_materialized_view`

Comment: Did you expect Alembic would automatically generate a migration script for your view? The best you can do in this case is write the migration script by hand, Alembic does not work with views as far as I know.